# Validity of the Re-Issue of Damaged Passport

Tags: indian-citizens, passport-renewals, vfs-global, damaged-passports

I recently applied for the Re-Issue of Indian passport due to expire within a year.

My Application was rejected by stating that Binding is damaged and I should reapply with new application and fees at VFS with Re-Issue of Damaged Passport.

I didn't notice any damage to the passport binding and was able to travel without any issues for years. I guess even if binding looks a little used, it might be considered Damaged.

Does anyone know what would be the validity of new passport once it's issued as part of Damaged Passport application type ?

Comment: Do you mean would you get a new passport with an expiry date of a year (the remainder of your damaged passport), or say 10 years (or whatever is normal for replacement Indian passports)?

Comment: That is the question I'm trying to get an answer for.

Answer (score 2):

From [Passport Services - FAQs](https://www.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqServicesAvailable)

> What is the procedure to apply for duplicate passport in case of lost or damaged passport?

> Duplicate passports are not issued however; a new passport with different passport number may be issued with fresh validity. The applicant has to apply in re-issue category with reason as Lost/Damaged passport.

Assuming you have an Ordinary Passport, its validity would therefore be the standard 10 years.

Comment: Thank you ! I went through the same FAQ section. But, I wasn't sure on what exact time frame fresh validity accounts for.

Answer (score 2):

I had applied for a re-issue of damaged Indian passport before. The validity will be 10 years from the date of reissue for adults and 5 years for children.

Comment: Awesome ! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the response.